# jQuery class remove works on fiddle but not on website

Tags: jquery

I wrote a jQuery script to change the class on a list element when you mouse over a label.  It works in Fiddle.  Doesn't work on the site.

On the live site, when you mouse over 'Market Sector' it should display a sub menu of choices.

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#navnav").hover(function () {
        $("#navnav>li.display-none").removeClass("display-none");
    },

    function () {
        jQuery("#navnav>li").addClass("display-none");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3egwq9gt/8/

LIVE SITE:

```
http://184.168.245.89/dev/test-gallery-2/
```

Answer (score 0):

The function works on the site when added in the web dev console. There seems to be an issue having the script inline in the head section, though jQuery is loaded before. You should just move the function to an external .js file, either to a new .js containing additional functions like this or to an already existing like the /wp-content/themes/Avada/js/main.js that already contains various helper functions and functions for the navigation and plugins  on your site.
Though this won't solve the issue, I've also noticed that there's a javascript error caused by /wp-content/plugins/media-grid/js/frontend_old_js.js line 336 - there the jquery `live()` function is called which is deprecated since jQuery version 1.7. If possible, just remove the include of this .js or, if you're not sure if part of this .js is still needed, just remove the code part below 'MediaGrid functions (v2.32) - old $ version' or comment it out to get rid of the error.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But it still doesn't work even attaching the js as an external file.  I disabled the Media Grid plugin that was kicking the error, thanks for that catch.